# JavaFX error on IntelliJ after running program SIGBUS (0xa)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

Hello everyone I receive and error when running a GUI application on JAVAFX on IntelliJ. I'm in my second semester with Java in college so now really sure what these errors mean but basically the program runs for a few seconds and then suddenly crashes on it's own. It's all random, can last 3 seconds or can last 15 seconds. I'm not sure what information is needed but I can provide for now what I'm using which is Java 17 and JAVAFX up to date. Mac mini M1. Intellij up to date.

```
#
#  SIGBUS (0xa) at pc=0x000000010a0514f0, pid=8179, tid=28687
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (17.0.1+12) (build 17.0.1+12-LTS-39)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.1+12-LTS-39, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, bsd-aarch64)
# Problematic frame:
# v  ~StubRoutines::SafeFetchN
#
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /Users/yayo/Documents/CSC 123/Projects/HeadsOrTails/hs_err_pid8179.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Both the M1 Mac mini and the JavaFX M1 architecture support are quite new.  JavaFX does have native code executing outside the JVM, it is feasible that it failed in your environment.  If you have access to other Mac systems (both M1 and Intel) or non-Mac systems, you might want to try your app there and see if only dies on your Mac mini.

Answer (score 2):

```
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
```

This is a broken configuration - not your code. An external library is being called by the JVM which causes the crash. You might need to update that manually. The error file written contains more troubleshooting information.

Comment: I've glossed over the error file provided but it's just a bunch of 0's and other information that I sadly don't understand at all. I could post it but its so long I'm pretty sure it would be bad manners.

Comment: You may want to enable core dumps, provoke a core dump, and use gdb to analyze it to see where it failed.   Normally the problematic frames listed are very helpful but not here.  `StubRoutines::SafeFetchN
#`.   I would suggest for now to reinstall Java and/or use another distribution.   Did you download the version of intellij with an embedded JVM?  If yes, contact JetBrains.